# Running function with async method in sequential order

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I have an array of function with async method inside it.I want to create a function which takes the array of function and execute the function in sequential order.I am not sure how to achieve it.Thanks for help.The functions are not async in nature.Its the method inside each functions

Example.

```js
function task1() {
  console.log('task1:started');
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('task1:finished');
  }, 5000);
}

function task2() {
  console.log('task2:started');
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('task2:finished');
  }, 5000);
}

function runner(tasks) {
  // help with implementation needed
  console.log('Desired Output:');
  console.log('task1: started');
  console.log('task1: finished');

  console.log('task2: started');
  console.log('task2: finished');
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.js: How to run asynchronous code sequentially](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27724323/node-js-how-to-run-asynchronous-code-sequentially)

Comment: Without taking a callback or returning a callback, you'll have a hard time to know when such a task is finished

Comment: @suraj.tripathi . I can't use .then property on functions because they are not async in nature.its the method inside each function which is async in nature

Comment: @MarutiNandan you'll need to rewrite those functions to either take a callback or return a promise. Is that an option?

Comment: @Mark_M I can't modify those functions

Comment: If these functions don't have any way of signaling when they are finished, there's not much you can do. This seems unusual since almost all async functions have some way - a callback, or promise - of letting you know they are finished.

Comment: @MarutiNandan any specific reason for not modify those functions

Comment: @MarutiNandan See the answer below - without providing a hook into completed computation of your tasks you won't be able to orchestrate them (e.g. run in sequence) in any way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Classic answer

You'll have to accept callbacks to achieve this, e.g.

```js
runner([task1, task2], function() {
  console.log('tasks done!');
})

function task1(cb) {
  console.log('task1:started');
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('task1:finished');
    cb();
  }, 100);
}

function task2(cb) {
  console.log('task2:started');
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('task2:finished');
    cb();
  }, 100);
}

function runner(tasks, cb) {
  if (!tasks.length) {
    return cb();
  }

  let index = 0;

  function run() {
    var task = tasks[index++]

    task(index === tasks.length ? cb : run);
  }

  run();
}
```

### Using `async.waterfall`

```js
async.waterfall([task1, task2], function() {
  console.log('tasks done!');
})

function task1(cb) {
  console.log('task1:started');
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('task1:finished');
    cb();
  }, 100);
}

function task2(cb) {
  console.log('task2:started');
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('task2:finished');
    cb();
  }, 100);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/async/2.6.0/async.js"></script>
```

---

### Promise-based implementation

```js
runner([task1, task2]).then(() => {
  console.log('tasks done')
})

function task1(cb) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    console.log('task1:started');
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log('task1:finished');
      resolve();
    }, 200);
  });
}

function task2(cb) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    console.log('task2:started');
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log('task2:finished');
      resolve();
    }, 100);
  });
}

function runner(tasks, cb) {
  return tasks.reduce((job, task) => job.then(task), Promise.resolve());
}
```

Comment: No need to make `run`, `next` and the anonymous callback three separate functions.

Comment: Not really, imo. You've also duplicated a lot of the code, like the `tasks.length` check. Also why would `index++` *not* be inside `next`?

Comment: You are entitled to your opinion, I won't engage in discussion of actual or perceived stylistic issues. You are free to provide a superior implementation.

Comment: I didn't mean to start a discussion either, I just wanted to give a tip and a reason why I didn't upvote despite the otherwise great answer :-)

Comment: @Bergi: Revisited the callback example and optimized for brevity.