# Google api SQL database dump via google cloud functions

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-sql, google-api-nodejs-client

With a node.js script via googleapis I done dump of all databases created on my Google SQL instance, the dump generate a single file for all databases which i store in a bucket. My target is to have one file for each database and not one file for all, the main problem is that if I run an export request for database A i can't run another for database B until the first is done.

Answer (score 0):

You may use [Async with callback](https://github.com/caolan/async) in order to run the exports sequentially, you may use the [operations list](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-api/rest/v1beta4/operations/list) method that will get you the status of the [exports](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-api/rest/v1beta4/operations#Operation) in order to be able to know when the export has finished and when to move to the next step using callback. For more information check this other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9644197/sequential-execution-in-node-js)

Comment: My first idea is similar, with a list of all databases names I call an export for first db, with returned data I know the name of operation and I can call operations.get with params project and operation name, but if the operation status returned is not DONE I need to re-call the same operations.get for get update about operation, how async can help me?

Comment: Maybe using a while loop until you confirm that the export is complete and using [sleep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14249506/how-can-i-wait-in-node-js-javascript-l-need-to-pause-for-a-period-of-time/41957152) for waiting a bit until each iteration could be an option

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to use a recursive function like this:

```
"use strict"
const { google } = require("googleapis");
const { auth } = require("google-auth-library");
const dateFormat = require('date-format');
var sqladmin = google.sql("v1beta4");
const project = "my-project-name";
const instanceName = "my-sql-instance-name";
const dbToDump = [];

exports.dumpDatabase = (_req, res) => {

async function dump() {
    let count = 0;
    let currentRequestName = '';
    const authRes = await auth.getApplicationDefault();
    var authClient = authRes.credential;

    let databases = await sqladmin.databases.list({
        project: project,
        instance: instanceName,
        auth: authClient
    });
    for (let i = 0; i < databases.data.items.length; i++) {
        const element = databases.data.items[i];
        // the system databases will be omitted
        if (
            element.name != "information_schema" &&
            element.name != "sys" &&
            element.name != "mysql" &&
            element.name != "performance_schema"
        ) {
            dbToDump.push(element.name);
        }
    }

    async function recursiveCall() {

        //exit condition  
        if (count >= dbToDump.length) {
            res.status(200).send("Command complete");
            return true;
        }


        // no request running
        if (currentRequestName == '') {
            // set data for next export call  
            var request = {
                project: project,
                instance: instanceName,
                resource: {
                    exportContext: {
                        kind: "sql#exportContext",
                        fileType: "SQL",
                        uri: 'gs://my-gsc-bucket/${dbToDump[count]}-${dateFormat.asString('yyyyMMddhhmm', new Date())}.gz',
                        databases: [dbToDump[count]]
                    }
                },
                auth: authClient
            };
            let r = await sqladmin.instances.export(request); //dump start
            currentRequestName = r.data.name;
        }

        // call to monitor request status
        let requestStatus = await sqladmin.operations.get({ project: project, operation: currentRequestName, auth: authClient });

        if (requestStatus.data.status == 'DONE') {
            // the current request is completed, prepare for next call
            count++;
            currentRequestName = '';
            recursiveCall();
        } else {
            // wait 10 seconds before check status
            setTimeout(recursiveCall, 10000)
        }
    }

    recoursiveCall();

}

dump();
};
```

This work for me, the only one more setting is to increase the timeout over the 60s.
Thank's Andres S for the support